# When is a sum of consecutive roots of unity an integer

Tags: number-theory, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $\xi \neq 1$ be an $n$th root of unity. When is a sum of the form
$$
1+\xi+\xi^2+\ldots+\xi^r, \quad 1 \leq r \leq n-1,
$$
an integer? What are the possible integers?

I suspect that the answers to both questions are the trivial ones: $r=n-1$ (or $\xi$ is not primitive and $r \mid (n-1)$) and the sum is $0$ in all cases.

Comment: $r=n$ is definitely another case.

Comment: I have restricted $1 \leq r \leq n-1$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $n\ne0$ or 1. Then $\xi^{r+1}-1=n(\xi-1)$. Now look at the geometry. Let $K$ be the point on the unit circle (in the Argand diagram) such that $\xi-1$ and $\xi^{r+1}-1$ lie on the ray $OK$. We must have the three distinct points 1, $\xi,\xi^{r+1}$ of the circle collinear. Contradiction.

Doing this on an iPhone6+ is challenging. Is that right?

Comment: This is a really nice approach to the problem!  You don't even need the diversion about $K$ (at least, not explicitly) - the condition is clearly enough to imply the mentioned collinearity of those three points.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki thanks. The diversion with $K$ and the rhombi was the way I *found* the solution!

Answer (score 0):

The following may be helpful for you:

$$
1+\xi+\xi^2+\ldots+\xi^r=\frac{1-\xi^{r+1}}{1-\xi}$$

You can discuss when $\frac{1-\xi^{r+1}}{1-\xi}$ is an integer, ecpeacially $\xi$ is an irrational number.